How can I Drag and Touch a widget simultaneously in Flutter?
I have recently implemented the tap through functionality in my flutter app also I have previously written the code for the dragging functionality as well but when I implemented the tap through function in my code the dragging logic code does not work Can anyone help me through this problem?
Also I have used the Overlap Pop Up flutter package to do so that has a plus point of showing overlay even after the app is killed so can anyone guide me throughout this problem. I was struggling for more than 2 days but unable to solve this problem. Anyone Who solves my problem Thanks a Lot. :(
import 'package:overlay_pop_up/overlay_pop_up.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isActive = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    overlayStatus();
  }

  Future<void> overlayStatus() async {
    isActive = await OverlayPopUp.isActive();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter overlay'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red[900],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final permission = await OverlayPopUp.checkPermission();
              if (permission) {
                if (!await OverlayPopUp.isActive()) {
                  isActive = await OverlayPopUp.showOverlay(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300,
                    closeWhenTapBackButton: false,
                    isDraggable: true,
                    backgroundBehavior: OverlayFlag.tapThrough,
                  );
                  setState(() {});
                } else {
                  final result = await OverlayPopUp.closeOverlay();
                  setState(() {
                    isActive = (result == true) ? false : true;
                  });
                }
              } else {
                await OverlayPopUp.requestPermission();
                setState(() {});
              }
            },
            color: Colors.red[900],
            child: Text(
              isActive ? 'Close overlay' : 'Show overlay',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

@pragma("vm:entry-point")
void overlayPopUp() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: OverlayWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class OverlayWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const OverlayWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: IgnorePointer(
        ignoring: false,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                top: 0,
                child: Draggable(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2.0),
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '•',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 40,
                        ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  feedback: Material(),
                  onDraggableCanceled: (_, __) {}, // Allow dragging
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

